# A bug I can't seem to spot. Faulty logic?

Tags: vba

Problem description:
Take a stack of coins all heads up.  Upturn the topmost coin, place back on the stack and then proceed:  take the top 2 coins and upturn as a single stack (tail, head becomes when upturned and placed back on the stack tail, head (the two coins are flipped as if glued together)).  Now in the same way flip the top 3 coins and place back on the stack (you get: tail, tail, head (and if there were 4 coins that would be tail, tail, tail, head).  When you upturn the whole stack begin again with the first coin.  Continue until you return to a stack with all heads up.

(Hope that's clear)

Can anybody see why this small program should fail?  The example for me where I first notice an error is when count reaches 18 with a stack of 6 coins.

In order to run the code:

- the currently selected WorkSheet must be named "Sheet3"
- on the active worksheet, enter the number of coins in the C1 cell.
- run the FlippingCoins() method

Code:

```
Sub FlippingCoins()
    Call theStackOfCoins
    Call theFlipping
End Sub


Sub theStackOfCoins()
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 3).Select
Columns("A:b").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("a3").Select

Dim StackOfCoins As Integer
    StackOfCoins = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 3).Value

Dim Flip_x_coins As Integer
    Flip_x_coins = 0

Dim row As Integer
    row = 0

For theStack = 1 To StackOfCoins
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(row + theStack, 1).Value = True
Next theStack

End Sub

Sub theFlipping()

Dim middleCoin As Integer
    middleCoin = 0
Dim passes As Integer
    passes = 0
Dim Fst As Integer
    Fst = 0
Dim Lst As Integer
    Lst = 0

Dim stack As Integer
    stack = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 3).Value

Dim count As Integer
    count = 0

Dim Finished As Boolean
    Finished = False

Reset:
    Flip_x_coins = 1
For Flip_x_coins = 1 To stack
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 4).Value = Flip_x_coins
    count = count + 1
    If Flip_x_coins = 1 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 1).Value = Not (Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 1).Value)
    Else
        passes = Int(Flip_x_coins) / 2
        Fst = 1
        Lst = Flip_x_coins
        For pass = 1 To passes
            If Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Fst, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Lst, 1).Value Then
                    Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Fst, 1).Value = Not (Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Fst, 1).Value)
                    Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Lst, 1).Value = Not (Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Lst, 1).Value)
            End If
            Fst = Fst + 1
            Lst = Flip_x_coins - 1
        Next pass
        If Flip_x_coins Mod 2 > 0 Then
            middleCoin = (Flip_x_coins + 1) / 2
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(middleCoin, 1).Value = Not (Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(middleCoin, 1).Value)
        End If
    End If
    For testComplete = 1 To stack
        If Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(testComplete, 1).Value = False Then
            Finished = False
            Exit For
        Else
            Finished = True
        End If
    Next testComplete
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 2).Value = count
If Finished = True Then
    Exit For
End If
    MsgBox "Next."
    If Flip_x_coins = stack Then
        GoTo Reset
    End If
Next Flip_x_coins

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards, Ian